# Xamarin Remote Simulator results in blank screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I know this feature is very new, so I'm hoping someone has had experience with this issue before and may shed some light on what might be going on. Right now we are trying to utilize Xamarin 4.2's new "remote iOS simulator for Windows". When I build to Mac simulator, it works fine the app shows up and no issues. When I turn on the option to use the remote simulator, the simulator opens, and then there's just a blank screen, as you can see from the screenshot there's no errors and it built fine:
[image: blank remote simulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are hitting the following:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42333

The remote simulator is in preview, so there are likely to be bugs that have not been fixed yet. I'd suggest adding a comment to that bug report with any information you can provide.

If you would like to receive a notification when the bug is updated, you can add yourself to the CC list for the bug.  Please note that you will need to create an account on that system if you have not already done so.

Comment: Yeah thanks. It's very weird because I've seen the simulator work for the guy at the conference, obviously he might have a better build, but I've seen it work around the net as well in random youtube videos. Thanks for the link, I'm surprised I didn't find that link in my x hours of research.